# Is fat burned even at caloric maintanance?

Tags: body-fat, metabolism, lipids, fatty-acids

I have searched up that it looks like for the bodies daily needs of energy it uses a combination of energy sources even stored body fat (Substrate utilization at Rest). But these sites are complicated to understand and do not mention whether this occurs even at caloric maintenance but I assume it does. And this would mean body fat is used for energy and resupplied as well in order for weight to remain constant each day when on caloric maintenance.

Here are the sources I used:

https://lllnutrition.com/mod_lll/TOPIC37/Old_version/m371.htm

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/lipid-metabolism